# Very basic SQL query in PyQt questions

Tags: sql, pyqt4

All example I've found are using PyQt to put data in various views and tables.

But I'm trying to do some very basic query to fetch data and send them to some other non-qt functions. Any advice how I can do this?

For example, if I query this from the table 'user' with 3 records. How do I access each record and return them as ordinary python string and not QtString?

```
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName(blah)

query = QtSql.QSqlQuery(db)
query.exec_("SELECT id, password FROM user")
```

Comment: You can always cast your string(s): str(myString)

Answer (score 2):

You are asking to access each record and return them as strings, but I think you mean to return the fields of each records as strings? Each record is an object containing the fields of your query. In this case, you asked for the id and password from user...

```
while query.next():
    record = query.record()
    id_ = str(record.value("id").toString())
    password = str(record.value("password").toString())
    print id_, password
```

You iterate over the query by looping while next() returns True. Each loop, you can ask for the QSqlRecord. With that record, you can ask for the value of each field. The value of each field is a QVariant. QVariant is a generic container than can hold different types, so you have to tell it to give you the value as a QString. A QString can easily be converted to a python string by str(qstring). Thus, you have your field values as python strings.